# Problem with12.04 install, grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I have an HP notebook with 2hard drives, /dev/hda & /dev/hdb. I have /home on hda and / on hdb. When I installed 12.04 I reformatted hdb which has the root and swap partitions and left the drive with /home untouched. Now when I try to boot I get the following:
error: no such device: 8796ed20-2210-4f37-aa38-9b80c883b77a.
grub rescue>

I have tried Rescatux and followed a coupleof threads to try and effect a repair to no avail. Any sggestions would be greatly appreciared

Answer (score 1):

I do a grub-install and let it discover the locations on it's own. More info here: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

but harisibrahimkv has a good way too. More than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Would grub-install automatically figure out the UUIDs? I don't think so because I had this problem with a swap partition and grub-install did not do the trick. I had to manually edit the /etc/fstab file.

Comment: yes because if forces you to specify the drive you would like to install  it on  and the scripts will extract the UUID from that drive.

Comment: Cool. :) I wonder why it did not work for me back then then.

Comment: Frank, I tried to reinstall grub from the live-cd but upon reboot I get the same error message as above.

Comment: have you tried switching sata cables or startup priority in the bios? Before you did the grub-install? You can try it know and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Frank, I have a notebook so swapping the cables won't work but I did change the startup priority and re-installed grub but no joy.ON reboot I get the same error message about no device and the incorrect UUID number. The numbers from "blkid" are the same in fstab and in /boot/grub/grub.cfg so I am at a loss to figure out where this number comes from. Thanks for your help, Robb

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sudo blkid /dev/hda" and "sudo blkid /dev/hdb" and get both of their UUIDS. Refer to this link http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/disk-drive-with-uuid-not-yet-ready-or-present-hibernation-option-missing/

After getting the UUIDS, see if those are the same ones in the /etc/fstab file. If not, change them and your boot should work properly.

Comment: Harisibrahimkv, using blkid I found that the UUID for both drives were the same as reported in fstab. I did notice that the grub.cfg file had the same UUID as I noted in the error message above. If I changed the grub.cfg file to use the same UUID as my /dev/hdb do you think that would cure the problem ?

Comment: They say you shouldn't tamper with with grub.cfg file manually because it is generated. But since your system is screwed, I don't think it will hurt trying to tweak it. Go ahead. :)

Comment: I just rechecked and I noticed that the UUID numbers that I got from using "blkid"  from the live-cd are the same ones used in /etc/fstab and the one used in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. But When I reboot I still get the error message saying "no such device: 8796ed20-2210-4f37-aa38-9b80c883b77a." Do you know of any other location that would have device UUID numbers that could be getting into the boot process ?